# Force Entity to return null if singleResult throw exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following code

```
return (EseshEntities.Current.Users.Select(u => new { Comunity = u.Apartment.Building.District.City })).ToList();
```

if building is empty then we got excpetion cos can't acces property of null right?
but is there any option in entity to instad of excpetion return just null, so if property
doesn't exist then return null?

Comment: Why not just build the where clause before you select to not return any null values?

Comment: Use DefaultIfEmpty instead of Select

Comment: I would guess he wants all users no matter if they go Comunity = null or not. I think u can't work around the check on null.

Comment: because this query in real live is much more commplicated and i want all rows even if they don't have key to exteranl property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this?

```
return (EseshEntities.Current.Users.Select(u => new { Comunity = u.Apartment.Building ==null?null:u.Apartment.Building.District.City })).ToList();
```

Comment: Agree, there does not seem to be another way

Comment: yee but look here we have u.Apartment.Building.District.City four properties, so this will look really complicated to check them all, it is pitty that there isn't just an option to make is if null then default even if foreig key is null.

Comment: properties are just wrappers for methods, so you can't call non-static methods if you don't have an instance

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var list = (from u in EseshEntities.Current.Users
            where u.Apartment.Building != null
            select new { Comunity = u.Apartment.Building.District.City }).ToList();
return list;
```

or you can try this:

```
return (EseshEntities.Current.Users.Select(u => new { Comunity = u.Apartment.ToInstance().Building.ToInstance().District.ToInstance().City })).ToList(); 

public static T ToInstance<T>(this T self)
{
    T mySelf = default(T);

    if (self != null)
        mySelf = self;
    else
        mySelf = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

    return mySelf;
}
```

Comment: no, i ask also in my query about few properties of user like userName or others, and this way i would exclude just all those users don't have building property.

Comment: I see, did you try initializing each property in a custructor of your entity classes? That way they are not null.